# How can I run a java program I wrote on a TI-84 Plus calculator?

Tags: java, calculator, ti-basic

I wrote a simple java program in which I input two numbers and then a little bit of information is printed in the console.

Do any of you know how I could run this on a [*TI-84 Plus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-84_Plus_series) calculator?

Comment: You almost certainly can't. Java requires a JVM, and the TI-84 is too small to have one.

Comment: From the article you linked to: *There are three different types of programs which can be downloaded or programmed into the calculators: TI-BASIC, Z80 assembly language, and Flash applications (also written in Z80 assembly)*. Do you see Java listed there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no java runtime for any Z80 processor, not even the TI-84. You might maybe get some chain of java-to-X compilers going but you'd probably still need to provide a base-platform layer to map the input/output system calls. In-short: there's no simple way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993221/multiple-language-programming-on-ti-calculator possible duplicate

Comment: @chrylis Who said Java needs a JVM to run?

Comment: Most certainly you will have to implement your own jvm. It seems possible, judging from projects such as [leJOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeJOS) which run on very minimal hardware.

Comment: @alexanders916 Java ONLY runs on the JVM, that it is why cross platform compatible. Before running java code, a JVM instance is created

Comment: @Meepo Nope, it's possible by compiling the byte/source code directly into machine code, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617865/how-to-run-java-program-without-jvm).

Comment: @alexanders916 I hope you understand that literally all code has to be translated to machine code. Compiling something directly to the native system comes with many problems, in addition JVM handles things like garbage collection which is why in languages like C you have to de allocate things on the heap yourself. It is not the same thing. Besides, writings a direct compiler from Java to the Ti-84 machine code is not viable.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to run Java on a TI-84.

However for simple programs you can use `TI-Basic` which is a simple language that you can code directly on your calculator. Simply do `prgm - new - create new` You then enter in the name of your program and press enter. You'll be brought to an editor in which you can put your code. Pressing `prgm` will bring up a menu with many basic functions such as `if` statements, input/output, and graphing.

Since typing on a calculator is pretty tiring, you can download the `TI Connect` app which let's you code on your computer then send it to your calculator.

Comment: Using Java Grinder is possible